# How do I print the top values in my dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.6

I am a computer science student and for my GCSE course we need to complete a NEA course.

I chose the task where we make a dice game and I am stuck on a bit where I sort a dictionary into the top 5 scores.

My code reads a leaderboards.txt and converts it to a dictionary. Below is Leaderboard.txt

```
12 p2
13 p1
1412 p5
34 p3
213 p6
9 p4
```

And now I cant find anywhere which tells me how I can sort a dictionary by the top values. Below is my code

```
highscores={}
with open("Leaderboard.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        (key,val) = line.split(" ")
        highscores[int(key)] = val
```

How can I print top 5 values in the dict? Thanks

Comment: I think you have to reverse your keys and values.

Comment: I can do that but the thing is how can I print the top 5 scores?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python 3.6, dictionaries are ordered by insertion order, so you need to extract all the keys and values, reorder them and then stick them in a new dictionary (limiting it to 5 entries whilst your at it)

```
original_dict = {
    12: 'p2',
    13: 'p1',
    1412: 'p5',
    34: 'p3',
    213: 'p6',
    9: 'p4'
}

sorted_items = sorted(original_dict.items(), key=lambda x: -x[0])

print({k: v for k, v in sorted_items[:5]})
```

```
{1412: 'p5', 213: 'p6', 34: 'p3', 13: 'p1', 12: 'p2'}
```

Comment: good answer, i would just add that for the users data they read data from a file so they will have string data so they will need to wrap `x[0]` as `int(x[0])` to be sure to sort score numerically.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle - Thats true although the op already does that in their question

Comment: Thanks it works,  do you know how I can print it so that when it is printed, It is in a better format?

Comment: @ICookixz - You need to iterate over the items in your output dictionary and then format them however you like

Comment: @Sayse ah ok it seems someone has edited the OP question changing int() to str()  for some reason on the dict key. I have updated the OP question to use int() again as it orignally did.

Comment: How can I do that? @Sayse

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```
from collections import Counter  

dct = {'p2':12,'p1':13,'p5':1412,'p3':34,'p6':213,'p4':9}
print(Counter(dct).most_common(5))
```

Output:

```
[('p5', 1412), ('p6', 213), ('p3', 34), ('p1', 13), ('p2', 12)]
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to sort the dictionary you would have to convert it to a type that can be sorted, such as a list. Alternatively, unless you have a particular need to use a dictionary, I would read the scores into a list to start with. That's a more suitable type for what you're attempting to do.